# display google map infowindow in a div outside with getElementeById

Tags: javascript, google-maps, getelementbyid, infowindow

I found myself stuck in this JavaScript problem with google map. I want to display the info of the marker in a div outside of the map with getElementById (or any other recommendation you provide).

I stored the info I want to display in the variable name that it doesn't display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var name;
    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351, 11.5820),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,

          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name, downloadUrl) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

Here is where I try to do the trick

```
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = name;
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;


      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}


  </script>


    <div id="map" style="width: 65%; height: 700px;float:left; display:inline;"></div>
  <div id ="mensaje">
    <p id="mensaje"></p>
  </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: I solved it
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = html;

It is html the variable i had to display

Answer (score 0):

The signature for your `bindInfoWindow` function is:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name, downloadUrl)
```

When you call it, you call it like this:

```
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```

So `name` and `downloadUrl` are `undefined` inside the function.  You don't use `downloadUrl` but you need to pass in `name` if you want to use it:

```
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vc8onnvj/2/)

Also, FYI you can't have multiple elements in HTML with the same `id`, `id` must be unique.  This is invalid:

```
<div id ="mensaje">
 <p id="mensaje"></p>
</div>
```

Either remove one of them or change one of the ids.

**code snippet:**

```js
var name;
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351, 11.5820),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  // downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var xml = parseXml(sampleXmlData); //data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    bounds.extend(point);
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  // });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = name;
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;


  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}
var sampleXmlData = '<markers><marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/><marker name="Buddha Thai &amp; Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar"/><marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant"/><marker name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="restaurant"/><marker name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bar"/><marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant"/><marker name="Mama&apos;s Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar"/><marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar"/><marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/></markers>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 65%;float:left; display:inline;"></div>
<div id="mensaje">
  <!-- can't have two elements with same ID <p id="mensaje"></p> -->
</div>
```